# Issues in displaying logs for Log4j

Tags: tomcat, log4j, tomcat7

Why Log4J logs are not getting displayed in my system(Server System,None of logs are getting displayed),while if any other accesses my server system,server hit logs are getting displayed in system.

Any Ideas what could be issue

Comment: are you using Log4j.properties file to configure?

Comment: Yes I am using that propery file to configure.